# Creating a Frequency Table Containing Word Lengths

Tags: java

I am trying to create a table with out using hash map or hasTokens to display the frequency of how many words of a file that have the same length show up. For instance, a word that has a length of 2 characters might show up 5 times in the whole text.

In the .txt file the longest word is 9 letters. How do I set up my code to analyze the file and then create a table that outputs how many times a word of a length of 1-9 characters has been spotted?

I have tried creating a for loop with a while such as :

```
for(int i= 0; i<word.length(); i++)
        {
        if (word.length()== 1)
        {
            System.out.println("The words with length of 1 are: " + i);

        }
    }
```

However it keeps on infinitely going on, but when I remove the while loop it fails. Hopefully someone will be able to give me a few hints on what to do. 
Thank you,
Jeff

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the HashMap ? An answer below will suit your needs perfectly but it uses a hashmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, the answer is simply to create an array of integers and index into it. This will be much faster and smaller:

```
final static int MIN_WORD_LENGTH=2;
final static int MAX_WORD_LENGTH=9;

int counts[MAX_WORD_LENGTH-MIN_WORD_LENGTH];  // allow for longer words :-)

private void addWord(int length) {
     if ((length >=2) && (length < MAX_WORD_LENGTH)) 
         counts[length-MIN_WORD_LENGTH]++;
}
```

I, personally would use a bigger array and get rid of the mapping and boundary checks. I would then create an exception handler higher up to catch anything out of range. Like this:-

```
 int counts[30];  // allow for longer words :-)

private void addWord(int length) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{
         counts[length]++;
}
```

A few bytes extra storage is not an issue on most modern processors, You'd save a lot more on code size. I'd get rid of the function call as well, it's here for clarity

Then to print:

```
void printCounts() {
     for(int i=0; i < 20; i++) {
         if (counts[i] >0) 
            System.out.printline("There are " + counts[i] + " words of length" + i); 
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and help. Definitely helped a lot. However, now I am  trying to separate a few select words from that whole file .txt and make them be listed out. For instance, a word that starts with a capital letter and ends with "ed" should be taken out from the whole file and printed out. My approach to this was to use a for loop to search for all the characters in the whole file  but I am having difficulty implementing it to search for caps as well                                                                                                              
            }

Comment: Hi Jeff, look at regular expressions, you can find these words quite easily with something like ([A-Z][a-zA_Z]*[e][d]). https://regex101.com/ gives you an online tester to tweak your RE. Java, python etc can be used to search your string, find multiple occurrences etc. They can be a pain to write and debug :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HashMap with the length as Key and the word count as value. E.g. for length 1-3 (untested):

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"aaa", "bbb", "x", "y", "rr", "tt"});
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
map.put(1, 0);
map.put(2, 0);
map.put(3, 0);
for(String word: words) {
    int cnt = map.get(word.length());
    map.put(word.length(), ++cnt);  
}
```

Comment: This method helped a lot as well and made and allowed me to become more familiar with HashMap. Thank you very much.